# Amazon DynamoDB Data Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Reading through the official documentation, we came to know that Amazon can support two Data Models.

1. Document Based
2. Key Value Based

DynamoDB doesn't seem to be asking for a preference while creating a table and neither did we find a default value somewhere.

Which of the two is actually used storing the data on Disk ?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about how data is stored. You are talking about a fully-hosted closed source database.

There is **one** DynamoDB.

Last year Amazon [introduced](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1DDAWQGXWITSG/Introducing-DynamoDB-Document-API-Part-1) "native" support for JSON and a new Document API. This is mostly related to the native support for Map and List attributes that allow to represent JSON(s) in DynamoDB.